# React js unit tests for connected components - mocha

Tags: reactjs, redux, mocha.js, react-redux, enzyme

I have a smart component, trying to write unit test (DOM tests) - getting the following error: Not sure why I am getting this error even though I am passing props in the test..?

> **Invariant Violation**: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(myComponent)". Either wrap the root component in
>   a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to
>   "Connect(myComponent)".

**Updated New error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'mainData' of undefined at mapStateToProps**

test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { renderComponent, expect } from '../../test_helper';
import myComponent from '../../../src/containers/myComponent';


describe('myComponent', () => {
  const mockStore = configureMockStore();
  let connectedApp,
    store,
    initialItems;
  let component;
  let componentRender;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const DataMock = [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
      2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

    const props = {
      mainData: DataMock,
      abc: 'def',
      subData: {
        test: '1',
        testing: 12,
      },
      userID: '1',
      Date: 'jan11',
    };

    initialItems = ['one'];
    const initialState = {
      items: initialItems
    };

    store = mockStore(initialState);

    component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <Provider store={store}><myComponent {...props} /></Provider>);

    componentRender = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component);
  });

  it('loads', () => {
    expect(component).to.exist;
  });
});
```

this myComponent is a child of a dumb component

myComponent code:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions/component_actions';

class myComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      someString: 'abc',
      someotherstring: 'def',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { test1, test2, test3 } = this.props;
    this.props.fetchEntriesDefault(test1, test2, test3);
    this.props.fetchAnalyticsMainView(test1, test2, test3);
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
     </div>
   );
  }
 }


    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return {
        mainData: state.reducerName.mainData,
        subDataData: state.reducerName.subDataData,
      };
    }
    myComponent.propTypes = {
      mainData: PropTypes.array,
      abc: PropTypes.string,
      subDataData: PropTypes.object,
      userID: PropTypes.string,
      actioncreatorfuncone: PropTypes.func,
      actioncreatorfunctwo: PropTypes.func,
      date: PropTypes.string,
    };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(myComponent);
```

Answer (score 2):

The error clearly states that, the `MyComponent` is connected to the store using `connect` from `redux`. Hence when you use the `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<myComponent {...props} />);`

The component tries to use redux to fetch the store that needs to be supplied. You need to create a test store in order for your connected component to receive reducer.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// IMPORTANT
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';

import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import { renderComponent, expect } from '../../test_helper';
import MyComponent from '../../../src/containers/myComponent';    

describe('myComponent', () => {
  var mockStore = configureMockStore();
  var connectedApp, store, initialItems;
  let component;
  let componentRender;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const DataMock = [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ];

    const initialState = {
      mainData: DataMock,
      userID: '1'
    };

    store = mockStore(initialState);
  });

  describe('state provided by the store', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {

      component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <Provider store={store}><MyComponent /></Provider>);

      componentRender = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component);
    });

    it('loads', () => {
      expect(component).to.exist;
    });
  });
});
```

In this way, you need to add the provider with the store for a connected component with redux.

**Update**
The `Actions may not have an undefined "type" property` is due to the fact that, in `myComponent` the connect method is not getting actions. Could you please post your entire code for `myComponent`? The actions that needs to be added? The actions should be a dictionary like:

Something like this example:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { login } from '../actions/creators/userActionCreators'

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    mainData: state.reducerName.mainData,
    subDataData: state.reducerName.subDataData,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
      onSubmitLogin: (id, pass) => dispatch(login(id, pass))
   }
};

// `LoginForm` is being passed, so it would be the "container"
// component in this scenario
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(myComponent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, updated my code but I get a new error - I have updated my question with the latest code - TypeError: Cannot read property 'mainData' of undefined, mainData is the exact word I am using in my component - am I passing the props right ? @ http://stackoverflow.com/users/308565/nagaraj-tantri

Comment: Updated the answer, since you need the `mainData` from redux state, you cannot pass it as `props`, you need to initialize it in `mockStore` like: `const initialState = {
      mainData: DataMock,
      userID: '1'
 };` and then `store = mockStore(initialState);`

Comment: tried it but same error - I have just updated the code of myComponent  - mainData: state.reducerName.mainData, is the issue related to reducername here? because the error says mainData of undefined in component - how to handle this from test case? http://stackoverflow.com/users/308565/nagaraj-tantri

Comment: @monkeyjs yes, its because, the object deep nest. Now, if your `mainData` is inside `reducerName` then ensure your test data is also the similar key value structure. So, `const initialState = {
      reducerName: { mainData: DataMock }    };`

Comment: I am getting Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant? Action: undefined
      at dispatch (node_modules/redux-mock-store/lib/index.js:39:19)
      at Object. actioncreatorfuncone (node_modules/redux/lib/bindActionCreators.js:7:12) - should I be doing something like this - const action = { types: 'ADD_ITEM' }

Comment: @monkeyjs nope, the `MyComponent` takes second parameter as `actions`, so it's because the mock store is not knowing the actions that are need to be specified. whenever you hit such roadblocks, use `debugger` inside the code and use chrome developers tools to see where is the data getting corrupted :)

Comment: something like this - <Provider store={store} actions={'FETCH_DATA'}><Entries /></Provider>); ?

Comment: @monkeyjs no, actions are defined in your component and not in test and hence not in `<Provider`. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: added the complete code of myComponent - ignore string name discrepancies but that is the whole structure how I have actions within the connect -http://stackoverflow.com/users/308565/nagaraj-tantri

Comment: @monkeyjs `import * as actions from '../../actions/component_actions';` is not giving the actions to connect method. Thats why you are getting `Action: undefined at dispatch...`. The actions should be an object of functions that return pure objects.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way I am doing is exporting the component separately just for testing as below.

```
export class MyComponent extends Component {
  // your stuff here
} 

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(MyComponent);
```

Here we will import component without redux wrapper for testing as

```
import { MyComponent } from '../../../src/containers/myComponent';
```

For reference [Testing Redux Component](http://ericnish.io/blog/how-to-unit-test-react-redux-components/)

Note: we will have to pass required props to the component.